# Android WebView TimeOut

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to set the timeout value in WebView?
I want the WebView to be timeouted if the url is too slow to response.

Comment: this shud help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7772884/169630

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by setting up a Timer which checks for progress of current page by calling [getProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getProgress())() and if it is less than some threshold after some specified time then you can dismiss the loading of the current page.

Comment: So do you mean i add timer and check the progress of current page by calling getProgress(), if it's not 100 yet i can call stopLoading().

Answer (score 5):

We can use `onLoadResource` method of `WebViewClient` instead of `Timer`. Like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.d("WEBCLIENT", "onPageFinished");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        Log.d("WEBCLIENT","onLoadResource");

        if(webView.getProgress() == 100) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if the web view is completely stuck.

Comment: If the webpage is stuck means, its progress will not be 100 , So the progress bar will be displayed until , the webView.getProgress() is 100

Comment: The question was not about progress bar, but timeout. This method would not work if the webpage loading gets completely stuck at some percent because none of these functions would get called, so there would be no possibility to take action.

Comment: yes you are right. Then a timer should be running untill the resources are loaded

Comment: great, save my time

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,String description, String failingUrl) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        Button btTryAgain = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_try_again);
        btTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                recreate();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        //Toast with error conection
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Where -alert_dialog- is a layout with a button to retry

Comment: inside your code, I see use of recreate(); on retry click. So, instead of recreate(); you may use WebView's reload() method. it will attempt to reload the entire web page.