# add webview with AndroidView in compose, come blank screen

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose, compose-android-vew

i used below code for add webview from Androidview in Compose, becuase i need to add js interface to it.

`

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
private fun Webview(screenVM: MainScreenVM = hiltViewModel()) {
    if (screenVM.showWebview.value) {
        AndroidView(factory = {
            val wv = WebView(it)
            wv.apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
                webViewClient = object : WebViewClientCompat() {
                    override fun onReceivedHttpError(
                        view: WebView,
                        request: WebResourceRequest,
                        errorResponse: WebResourceResponse
                    ) {
                        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse)
                        screenVM.showWebview.value = false
                    }
                    override fun onReceivedError(
                        view: WebView,
                        request: WebResourceRequest,
                        error: WebResourceErrorCompat
                    ) {
                        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                        screenVM.showWebview.value = false
                    }

                    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                    }

                }
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.allowContentAccess = true
                settings.allowFileAccess = true
                addJavascriptInterface(MyJavaScriptInterface(context, wv), "AndroidFunction")
                loadUrl(URLS.SUPPORT_SHORTCUT_PAGE)

            }

        }, update = {
            it.loadUrl(URLS.SUPPORT_SHORTCUT_PAGE)
        })
    }
```

`

but when load webview, screen blank for a second and later show webview.
1- i can add js interface to

```
accompanist-webview
```

?

2- else, why screen blank for a secon when load webview in compose?

Comment: webview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);   set this

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI doesn't work

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304171/how-to-manage-the-blank-white-loading-screen-of-an-android-webview

Comment: this is a bug for compose and not work those solutions

Comment: any error comes

Comment: no only show a blank screen with webview part , when touch webview, show compose components