# Implementing timeout in webviews

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I need to implement timeout for my webviews. I want to show the user n error message if the webpage could not be loaded within a desirable time. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Android WebView TimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302912/android-webview-timeout) 
You basicly have a timer that checks the progress of the webview at some time intervals by calling [getProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getProgress%28%29). If the progress hasen't reached your chosen threshold value after a specific time you call the error message.

Another answer: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/04a817864dc86383

Answer (score 0):

You may use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, int delayInMillisec)` method after `webview.loadUrl()` or `webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl()`