# webview.loadurl times out in android default browser in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I am trying to load a url using simple **webview.loadurl** and it *times out* after 30 seconds or so.

I went ahead and **tried hitting the same url from default android browser**(comes with most samsung devices) and there also it doesn't load and gives error in 30 seconds

I tried the same with chrome browser and the page loads in about 2:30 minutes. Is there a way to increase timout duration in android? or is there a way to set the client to chrome always. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For setting of chrome client:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

For setting of timeout you may refer to

[set loadURLTImeOutValue on webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772409/set-loadurltimeoutvalue-on-webview)

Comment: i have tried setting the above webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); but this times out as well. Also the 2nd link which is using DroidGap works only when i use a local URL and not a web url.