# Timeout on Webview Android

Tags: android, timeout

Is there a way to set the timeout value in `WebView`? I want the WebView to be time-outed if the url is too slow to response or if the site doesn't load in 10 seconds.

I don't know really where I should start :(

I have 2 classes, the first one is starter and the second one is for `webView`. Starter is a kind of thread and splash-screen for start and the next activity is the main `webView`, so I would like to add a checker if the site doesn't response in 4 10 secs, it would give a error.

I hope any of you can help me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darpans code will not work, not at least because the parameter progress will not change during `while`, only by next call of. Try this instead:

```
private long starttime = 0;
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    Log.v(TAG, "progressChanged: " + progress);
    if(progress == 10) starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long secondsSinceStart = (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) / 1000;

    if(progress < 100) {
        Log.v(TAG, "seconds since start: " + secondsSinceStart);
        if(secondsSinceStart > 5){
            view.stopLoading();
            Log.d(TAG, "TIMEOUT -> Stopped.");
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, progress + "% completed in: " + secondsSinceStart + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this will only work if the connection to the server will be established. If not the `onProgressChanged` get called only two times: at 10 and at 100 percents when then load is aborted.

Comment: You are right.. it will not work. Gotta change 'while' to 'if'.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by setting up a Timer which checks for progress of current page by calling [getProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getProgress%28%29) and if it is less than some threshold after some specified time then you can dismiss the loading of the current page.

Comment: Can u help me more with the the solution please? u have some example i can follow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4303028/609782 . A implementation of the same would help us learn better. Copy paste would not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to implement a timer that will check the progress and triggers action if it takes more than a certain time to load the page.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    Long seconds = (long) 0.0;
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        Date interestingDate = new Date();

        // second < 5 here you can use your desired time you wish to wait for.
        while (progress < 100 && seconds < 5) {
            //following line calculates time difference
            //between current time and time when page started loading.
            seconds = ((new Date()).getTime() - interestingDate.getTime())/1000;
        }

        if(progress < 100 && seconds > 5) {
            view.stopLoading();
            Log.d("###", "stopped");
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, my edit was hasten and now I cannot roll it back. But tell me please which Seconds you mean and how to get that compiled.

Comment: My apologies but I didn't get your question, can you please explain?

Comment: You wrote `Seconds=(Long)0;`– I was not aware of that Type, only of the Enum `TimeUnit` so I overhasty edited your post and added that TimeUnit. Then there was the time to paste your code and I got a problem: neither `TimeUnit.Seconds=(Long)0;`nor `Seconds=(Long)0;` is syntactically correct and could become compiled. At least in eclipse Juno with the ordinary ADT libraries and with JDK 1.6. But I'm happy every time I can learn new stuff, so I tried to figure out under which conditions you could compile it if you could at all. Thanks for the time anyway ;)