# Android Java - WebView Max Loading Time

Tags: java, android, android-webview

How can I make my WebView show the error page if the loading time for a page exceeds 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302912/android-webview-timeout) you could keep a timer and if it exceeds your 5 seconds timer show the error page to the user.