# How to check if a WebView is empty or not Android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am fetching an url into a WebView. I want to know Whether the WebView is empty or not after it finished fetching the data, so that I can process further. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352700/how-to-check-url-is-loaded-in-webview-or-not