# XML Splash Screen -> Display Webview

Tags: android, xml, cookies, webview

Thanks for trying to solve my problem!

Currently my app basically loads a web page using the Android Web view. The downside is that sometimes (with a bad connection) the web page takes over 10 seconds to load. Is there a way I can create some sort of splash XML "loading" screen while the web page is loading?

Take a look at my code...

```
package com.ect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //THIS IS WHAT I WANT: setContentView(R.layout.main);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getBaseContext());

        // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
        // browser app does.


        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);


        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
             activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
      });

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
});

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

     //This will load the webpage that we want to see
      webview.loadUrl("http://www.web.com/");

   }
}
```

That is my code. If you look closely I made a comment that says, "THIS IS WHAT I WANT: ..."

That comment would call the main.xml file to be displayed, but if I use that comment the main.xml file will be displayed, but the webview never appears...

**How can I display the main.xml file and then (once the the web view loads) display the webpage?**

Comment: Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199717/how-can-i-know-that-my-webview-is-loaded-100), I believe this has been answered already. It basically overrides some methods of the WebViewClient class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a WebViewClient object and override the `onPageFinished()` method. Then use `webView.setWebViewClient()` to set the WebViewClient object you created above to the WebView. Now you can run some code in `onPageFinished()` such as `setContentView()` to change the content view from the loading screen to the web view when it has finished loading.

This tutorial might help you a bit, although it isn't exactly what you need. http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1331

Answer (score 3):

You must use the event onPageFinished().

Here is the official reference [Clickme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

Your main activity must setContentView(R.layout.main); and the function onPageFinished() must setContentView(webview);

Comment: Thanks Piperoman! I'm completely new to developing with Android... Is there any way you can kind of give me some code?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, In you layout root Frame layout (or relative layout) do something like this.

```
<Framelayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
....>

    <Webview android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <include android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    layout="@loadingLayout"/>

</Framelayout>
```

When the web view finishes loading then simply change the included components visibility to Gone.

I hope it helps..

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have all the code, but I will try and post a more complete example when I can.