# Android webview listening for errors and loading dialog

Tags: android, android-webview

According to some highly-regarded answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172952/346613),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199854/346613)), the following code should open a website in a webview and then listen for errors on the page. However, it fails at the first hurdle - the website (google) in the webview doesn't load (I definitely have an internet connection). Why is that? Moreover, if you open the drawer with the android back button and click "try again/refresh", the drawer successfully disappears and the loading dialog appears, but then it stops responding to the back button.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/error.html");
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_refresh) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: First,  

You probably did, but make sure you added Internet permission:  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  

Second, I think your problem is with the shouldOverrideUrlLoading().  Try it as follows:  

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
        return false;
    }

The method is to prevent a URL from loading.  By returning "true", you're stopping the original load, but loading the same URL again.  

And finally, onReceivedError() is for HTTP errors, not errors from the WebView.

Comment: If someone could tell me how to properly format this, I'd appreciate it.  I've looked at the markdown but it doesn't work so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Another point, try it with a different URL, such as StackOverlow:

    webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

The page finishes loading and properly closes your dialog.

Comment: Alas `return false` doesn't change anything, nor does trying the stackoverflow url. 
From you last comment, do I understand that my posted code above worked for you? You got stackoverflow.com to open in the webview with this code? So it works for you but not for me?
(Formatting: have you tried putting code inside two backticks?)

Comment: Yes, with the changes I mentioned, your code works for me.  (I removed the `view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");` line and returned false from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.  

I could try posting the full code, or better, upload it for you.  

(Thanks for the tip on inlining the code... now I wish I could understand how to do multi-line samples.)

Comment: Interesting. I'm baffled. Would you mind uploading your code?
When I do `webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");` before `setWebViewClient` instead of inside it, the webpage appears, so I definitely have an internet connection.
(Check this out: [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, when you're making a comment, a 'help' link appears with formatting stuff in.)

Comment: Here's a link: https://gitlab.com/NightSkyDev/WebViewTest.git  
And yes, I've reviewed the Markdown help, but what exactly do I use to format code?  I've tried <code>, indenting with four spaces, etc, but they don't format the code.

Comment: Indenting four spaces should work. The only thing I can think of is maybe you're not leaving a blank line before the four space indent? It doesn't work directly after text.
Thank you for the upload. I finally got it working and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The error was in

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
    view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return true;
}
```

which should be

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
    view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
    return true;
}
```

And then load the actual url outside the setWebViewClient:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```