# Android Webview does not load the url

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I would like to load an website via WebView. When it loads via web browser,there is no problem. But when I try to load via WebView, Nothing loads. A white blank background shows instead.

Here is MainActivity class(Here, it is Main class):

```
package com.xamarin.gcmexample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView mWebView;
     Logger LOGGER;
    private static Main  mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationIntentService.class.getName());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mContext =Main.this;
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String id=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
       if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://pavementworks.corelynx.com?imei="+id);                             
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        } 
        }catch(Exception ex)
        { LOGGER.info(" mWebView:"+ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mContext =Main.this;
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationIntentService.class.getName());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String id=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://pavementworks.corelynx.com?imei="+id);                             
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }       
    }
}

 class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        //You can add some custom functionality here
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //You can add some custom functionality here
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        //You can add some custom functionality here
    }
}

class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    Activity activity;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void closeActivity() {
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Here is my Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.xamarin.gcmexample.Main">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: The resulted Image]

Am I doing any wrong? Please give suggestion.

Comment: any exceptions ???

Comment: Are you sure that ResultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS is true??

Comment: `loadUrl` and intent both are firing same time

Comment: @Sr. Pulgarin, Yes I am sure because the second activity works well and also I have tested sample line in log under the control statement "ResultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS" which  works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add permissions into your Manifest file.

```
<Manifest> 

...

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

...

</Manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have already implemented this  one.

Comment: @ManasMaity - Just checking. I always forget that part.

Comment: Can I use chrome as default webview programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

```
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://pavementworks.corelynx.com?imei="+id);                             
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

In that case `loadUrl` and `Intent` firing same time . What is `if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)`

1. Remove `Intent intent` Section .
2. FYI : **WebView** showing `Your connection is not private`
3. Make sure `resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` Properly Satisfied or not

Comment: @inteliJ Amiya, Thanks for your response. After succesfully loading the website I need to do another activity. If I remove the intent from the above place then where should I put it ? Please explain. Thanks again.

Comment: @ManasMaity Goto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199717/how-can-i-know-that-my-webview-is-loaded-100 . When 100% loadad then add intent

Comment: @ManasMaity check above link .i faced it . Hope this helps you .

Comment: and make sure add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: @ManasMaity Let me feedback please .

Comment: Armiya I have gone through your provide url and implemented the required steps but alas! the problem is not solved.

Comment: @ManasMaity see this logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android/30325536#30325536

Answer (score 0):

1. public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
   -> **should return false**
2. **Override this method:**

   ```java
   @Override    
   public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {    
       // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);    
       handler.proceed();    
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually it's bad example and Google Play will throw a security alert. We should add dialog to let user decide whether he want to avoid SSL error or not.