# Remove Javascript item from WebView android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

Hello I'm using `WebView` to display website have some buttons and I need to remove them in the `WebView`I used this code but nothing happened for example my class name is (vtLYrb imso-loa DAPhHc) I need to remove it here is my code

```
// ...
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
        "document.getElementByClassName('vtLYrb imso-loa DAPhHc')[0].style.display='none'; " +
        "})()");
    }

});

mWebView.loadUrl(youUrl);
```

Comment: Have you enabled JavaScript in your WebView?

Comment: of course i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method name of getting all elements with the specified class name is `getElementsByClassName()`

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
            "document.getElementsByClassName('vtLYrb imso-loa DAPhHc')[0].style.display='none';" +
            "})();");
}
```

Comment: works like a charm but after the full page loaded they appears again ?

Comment: `window.onload` seems not a solution. I suggest take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199854/9311972

Comment: Still the Same problem