# Loading special site with webview

Tags: android, webview

I want loading site in webview but when using , not showing.
I want loading this site web.rubika.ir in webview and send requests.
How do I do this? Only this site .

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to load a url in your webView

```
webView.loadUrl("Your URL Here")
```

additionally if you want to get notified whether your url is still loading or finished you can have a look at this [get notified when webview loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199717/how-can-i-know-that-my-webview-is-loaded-100).

You can show a progress bar while loading url which will help to understand that web view is loading.

Comment: I did all that said. But it did not work. I do not know, maybe the site is unique so that it can not be opened with webview. You can do a test and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. in layout file (.xml) of this activity, use webview widget

   ```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   ```
2. Then in onCreate method of the activity, use webview.

   ```
    WebView wv;
    wv = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.loadUrl("web.rubika.ir");
   ```
3. If you want to enable javascript support

   ```
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ```
4. Make sure you have declared Internet permission in manifest.xml

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
5. then in Application tag of you manifest add this;

   ```
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   ```

6.Done.

Comment: Tx @dani3264 .I did all that said. But it did not work. I do not know, maybe the site is unique so that it can not be opened with webview. You can do a test and tell me the result.