# how to stop the web view and display a reload message if the page does not load for 30 seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, webkit

I have a web view and i have this code (P.S i am a beginer in programming)

```
private WebChromeClient getChromeClient() {


        return new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressDialog.show();
                if (newProgress ==100){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        };
    }
```

I already have webview client and webchrome client, you can see and download my code files here (cloud.mail.ru/public/2hHz/25DMkxh3U)

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (mbErrorOccured == false && mbReloadPressed) {
                hideErrorLayout();
                mbReloadPressed = false;
            }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mbErrorOccured = true;
            showErrorLayout();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    }
```

At the top you can see my code in Main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how to find if the webview loaded completely at this link :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199717/how-can-i-know-that-my-webview-is-loaded-100)

Once you start loading the webview, you can start a handler and check if the page is loaded completely, or you can reload the webpage.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // check if the webview is loaded completely after 30 seconds here
            
            //if the page is not loaded then call the below line to reload
            // mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }, 30000);
```

Comment: I updated the message at the top, but where should I write your code?

Answer (score 0):

Override Webviewclient class and start a countdowntimer in onPageStarted method and cancel the timer in onPageFinished , invoke your method in onfinish of countdowntimer.