# How to add a loading image to webview?

Tags: android

I'm working with a webview in my android app... everytime I open an url my page is blank and after a while the url content appears... how can I add a loading image in webview during this transition time?? I tried to call open twice, first time loading a local content and next time the real url I wanted to feed but it doesn't work, I think that something wrong with async calls.

Thanks in advance ^^

regards

Comment: [Check this out: How to show loading image or progress bar on WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776146/how-to-show-loading-image-or-progress-bar-on-webview)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'm doing it.

In my main layout I have spots for the WebView and an ImageView.  The WebView starts off 'gone' and the loadingimage is 'visible'.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/loadingimage"
        />
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the java I load the URL.  Once the URL is done loading, I swap out the loading image for the WebView.

```
        WebView wv;
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            //this is to catch link clicks on your page, to prevent opening a new browser
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });         
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.yourdomain.com/blahblahblah.htm");
```

Please note: the onPageFinished method I use here works fine for my simple application, however, it might not work for your case.  For deets about how to fully listen for a page to finish loading, see this thread --> [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android)