# How to show loading image or progress bar on WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webView in android that loads a particular site, i want to display a loading icon or progress bar on clicking any of the links inside the webView.

```
    webViewClient = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer);

    WebSettings webSettings = webViewClient.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webViewClient.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webViewClient.loadUrl("URL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            showProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    }


    webViewClient.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 webViewClient = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer);

    WebSettings webSettings = webViewClient.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webViewClient.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             activity.setTitle("Loading...");
             activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100)
                   activity.setTitle("Your Title");
             });

    webViewClient.loadUrl("URL");

Following Link May help you as well : http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to figure out when the click happens :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                webView.loadUrl(url); 
                // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL' 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```

Then, you have to put the `Progressbar` in a `FrameLayout` with your WebView.

```
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Progressbar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

So, when the click happens, you can show your progressbar inside your Activity.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            if (url.equals("your_url"){
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```