# Non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Looking at this [How to show loading image or progress bar on WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776146/how-to-show-loading-image-or-progress-bar-on-webview) it clearly says that the following approach should work but I am having an issue as I cannot access my `ProgressBar` in `public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)`

My Code is the following

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());                    
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", HTML_DATA, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Where my `WebViewClientClass` is the following

```
#region Webview URL handler
internal class WebViewClientClass : WebViewClient
{    
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri url = request.Url;
        view.LoadUrl(url.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
         base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
         Log.Info("101028", "loading started");
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.Info("101028", "loading finised");
        PB.Visibility = ViewState.Gone; ***<<<<<<<------ ERROR HERE***
    }
}
#endregion
```

I can see the results in logcat but when I try to access my `ProgressBar` such as `PB.Visibility = ViewState.Gone` in `OnPageFinished` method - I get the following error

> ERROR

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property**

PogressBar Code

```
private ProgressBar PB;

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Read);
    PB = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.MyProgressBar);
}
```

Anyone knows what is the right approach for this? How do i make this work

Cheers

Comment: Looks like there's some other `PB` type that it's trying to access instead of your PB variable... did you tried to rename it?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza that is not definitely it. The compiler says it as is. PB is declared in the `Activity`, which is out of scope of the `WebViewClientClass` so he either need to pass in `PB` as an argument or make it static if he is declaring the `WebViewClientClass` as a nested class.

Comment: @Cheesebaron You're absolutely right. What the hell I had in mind¿?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems that your `ProgressBar` belongs to your `Activity` and you are trying to access it in `WebViewClientClass` that's why your object reference is missing.

So you should have a method inside your activity class which will hide/show `ProgressBar` and there must be some kind of call back mechanism to call this method

Define an interface like below

```
interface ProgressBarHandler{
    public void hideProgress();
}
```

And in your activity class implement this interface

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements ProgressBarHandler{
    //other usual things in your activity

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //here pass the activity instance to WebViewClientClass
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass(this)); 
    }

    public void hideProgress(){
        PB.Visibility = ViewState.Gone;
    }
}
```

AND finally in your `WebViewClientClass`

```
class WebViewClientClass : WebViewClient
{    
    private ProgressBarHandler handler;
    public WebViewClientClass(ProgressBarHandler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.Info("101028", "loading finised");
        handler.hideProgress();
    }
}
```