# Android: overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading not working on HTC devices

Tags: android, webview, overriding

On a HTC Evo running Android 2.3.5, overrriden `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is never called. The exact same code works well on a Samsung Galaxy running Android 2.3.6.

so far, I have tried overriding `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()`. I do not see the URL in these methods.

My intent is to provide custom activities for `mailto:` and `tel:` links present in the page. Any ideas on how I can make this work if `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is never hit?

I have already looked at similar questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere, haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: [took from ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670136/shouldoverrideurlloading-gets-called-only-for-some-webpages). The problem seemed to be js function setTimeout(fn, millis). You have write a js function that overrides it and then recreate the behaviour of this function in your Android code (using JavascriptInterface) as it fits best for your app. It's a lot of work which depends of your app functionality, but it works. The idea is overriding setTimeout then call a method from android code who sleeps the thread for how many millis were in the initial calling of the setTimeout in js..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll give it a try; but Javascript might not be an acceptable solution. I am also looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Answer (score 4):

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` doesn't work only on some Android versions, like 2.1 or 2.3.6 but it works fine on 2.3.3, 2.3.5, 4.0.2 or 4.0.3.

If you need to handle clicking on a link on webview, you must use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. If you only need to handle loading a webpage, you should use `onPageStarted()`.

This is android developer link: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

- Note: Ex: we have 2 links on Webpage.

  1. `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools!</a>`
  2. `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>`

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is only called when user click on link "`1`".
and it isn't called when user click on link "`2`"

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    if (url.contains("success")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WebviewActivity.this, OrderConfirmActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the ` if (url.contains("success"))` works. Could you explain it?