# webview never call ShuldOverrideUrlloading in webviewclient in android

Tags: java, android

I have a webview and a link on the URL that I have loaded on that webview, I want such like that if user clicks in this link the app will go to the background and open that link with the default web browser of that device. To do this I have done the following:

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null
                        && url.startsWith("http://the6figuremarketer.com/apps/androidfb21/thks.html")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        web.loadUrl("http://the6figuremarketer.com/apps/androidfb21/index.html");
```

but I figured out that the `shouldoverrideurl` method is nevet get called. what should I do now? can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [shouldOverrideUrlLoading in WebView for Android not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738328/shouldoverrideurlloading-in-webview-for-android-not-running).

shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called when you call loadurl on webview. It is called only when you click on a link in webview.