# Android Webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading method

Tags: android, android-webview, uri, android-assets

When is `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method called?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


    }
});
```

1. Is it called during initial loading of url? e.g. `webView.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/html/index.html");`
2. Is it called everytime URL of webview changes?

Any reference? I didn't find one. Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6739042/1503078). I've also checked, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not called when using loadUrl

Answer (score 10):

1. It does however, get called when the WebView to load a different URL from the one the user had requested.
2. Calling `loadUrl()` will also trigger the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. (Only when a new url is about to be loaded.)

> ***Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.*** If
>   WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity
>   Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. If WebViewClient is
>   provided, return true means the host application handles the url,
>   while return false means the current WebView handles the url.

Ref : [public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: No, simply calling `loadUrl()` will NOT trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. Only when a new url is about to be loaded.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Hey thanks for your precious downvote. It will help me to learn the concept once again :). Please add your answer, so it will be helpful for others and me too.

Comment: If you edit your message so people won't be mislead by your answer and lose precious time, I'll be very happy to upvote again :)

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Updated answer with your comment.

Comment: @PankajKumar `loadUrl` does not `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` trigger. Could you elaborate the second point?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer for your both the questions:

As per the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), it will manage every time new URL is about to load in current WebView.

Comment: how about the initial url loaded in the webview?

Comment: @JRGalia above answer is for both the questions.