# Android Studio - Webview - shouldOverrideUrlLoading - Do not open web browser

Tags: android, url, webview, redirect

I developed a Webview app with Android Studio but when the user clicks a link from a web page in the WebView, Android is opening the default web browser.
I already checked on Android Developers API Guides how to do but it does not work ;( on my app ... Guides Link: [Handling Page Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation)

Who know how to use the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method" and how to insert it in my actual app?

Thanks

// MainActivity.Java

```js
package com.blabla.blabla;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Application;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.blablablablablabla.com/");

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID Blablabla",
                "ID Blablabla");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation()
                .saveInBackground();
    }

}
```

// activity_main.xml

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

// Android Manifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blabla.blabla" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.blabla.blabla.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.blabla.blabla.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.blabla.blabla" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669046/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I just added

```js
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
```

and

```js
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

To my MainActivity.java file... It is work great!!!