# Trying to parse JSON of a web page before it's loaded in a WebView

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-webview, android-volley

I need to parse JSON content out of every page in my WebView, before it is shown to the user.

In order to do so, I need to parse the JSON element and only then I’m able to use the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. I can’t use it before I’ve parsed the JSON object because I rely on that element as part of my implementation of that method.

---

I have created a variable called `jsonParsed` to indicate whether I have all needed information out of the JSON object. 
At first, it is initialized to be false.
When I get a response from the server I know the object was parsed so I change the variable to be true in the `onLoaded` method, and then the code is ready to get the information and check it.

---

This is the wanted process:

1. Opening new page by the user
2. Entering automatically to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and then to the `if` statement(JSON wasn't parsed yet)
3. Getting the JSON response in `OnResponse`
4. Going back to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and entering the `else` statement (JSON is parsed)

As you can see, each process should go through both `if` and `else` statements, the `if` before the JSON was parsed, and the `else` after it was parsed.

---

**The problem:**

**`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is reached every *step 1*, but each time it goes into a different statement. The first time goes into the `if` *(steps 2+3)*, and the next one goes into the `else` *(step 4)* and this process repeats itself...**

**I think the this line `webView.loadUrl(loadingURL);` doesn't call `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` for some reason.**

---

**Here is my code snippet:**

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
     super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
     mProgressDialog.show();                        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url){
                                    loadingURL=url;
            if (!jsonParsed){
            /** JSON object is not parsed
            * Some code for adding request 
to requestQueue and than loading new url in onResponse method... */                          
            }

            else {                         
        /** JSON object is parsed, starting checking process
        * I need to check this URL and decide whether or not to override it*/                               
          jsonParsed=false;
          Root root = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, Root.class);
          for (Page page : root.query.pages.values()) {
          firstParagraph=page.extract; //Parsing process, works fine
                                        }
          if (firstParagraph!=null) {
         //If the webView isn't Wikipedia's article, it will be null
         if (firstParagraph.contains(allowedContent)) {
        //Passing URL to view
         return true;
         }
    }
     return false; //The URL leads to unallowed content  
                                    }
                                }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     CloseBlocksAndDisableEdit(view);
      mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                         }

    private final Response.Listener<String> onLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
         jsonResponse=response; //Getting response
         jsonParsed=true; //Object was examined
         webView.loadUrl(loadingURL);
       }
    };
```

**What can be the cause of this problem?

If it's not possible in this way, I'd like to know which way is better...**

Comment: Please be more specific on your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question and tried to be more specific.

Comment: What ever statement you use inside webview client is got looped...meaning you have to use catch mechanism to get what you want and end the loop.

Comment: I didn't really understand what has got looped here. I have edited my question, trying to find more specific problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739042/7483311

It is written in this answer:

> After some research I conclude that despite what most of the tutorials
>   out there say, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() does not get called when:
>
> 1. You load a URL like:
>      loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
> 2. The browser redirects the user automatically via an HTTP Redirect.

This probably makes my code impposible. 
In this line: `webView.loadUrl(loadingURL);`, I'm making an https request that was not made by the user in the WebView, and that's why it doesn't call `shouldoverrideurlloading`.