# Anyway To tell when content in a webView is fully loaded?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to tell if content retreived from a URL into a WebView is full loaded?

EDIT: I am trying to display a indetermined progress widget until the webview is fully loaded?

How would i implement this with WebView.getprogress()?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android/5172952#5172952

Comment: When you mean spinner, do you mean an indeterminate progress widget (the spinning wheel). Or do you literally mean the drop down menu?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. I mean indeterminate progress widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `WebView.getProgress()` and see if it's at 100%.

EDIT: Add this to your `WebView`:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android/3149260#3149260).

Answer (score 3):

For the indeterminate progress spinner, create a ProgressDialog and show it when you start loading the webpage. Then in the `onPageFinished()` add the `ProgressDialog.dismiss()` to close it. Refer to this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to see how to make progress dialogs.

Comment: so WebView has a method onPageFinished? or i create the method as you did above?

Comment: Well you implement the interface WebViewClient by calling `webView.setWebViewClient()` and then replace the dismiss dialog method inside where the `onPageFinished()` method is. Pretty much, copy and paste the code snippet above and replace the variable names of course. Let me know if there are any more questions!

Comment: Usually on stackoverflow I like an answer so much that I wish I could upvote it twice. Well, this is one of those rare scenarios, where I actually can ;)