# Detect post call from webview history

Tags: android, webview

I want to check whether a call in webview url is a post or a get call.. Is there any way to check from Webview history that the previous URL was a "post" call or a "get" call?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your GET or POST requests send at least one variable to the server, then you can check if the previous request was a GET by retrieving the URL from the history and seeing if there are any parameters in the URL. For a GET you would expect `mypage.html?param=value`.

See this for getting the browsing history:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7763254/483708

See this for parsing an URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342549/483708