# How to load web page on webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I was trying to make a very basic program to load the web page on a web view in the `onCreate()` method of my main activity, but it always asks to me load that url on my inbuilt web browsers. How can I load the web page on a webview?

Comment: What code you had done for that ?

Comment: You need to show the code you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to load a url to webview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

Comment: and don't forget to add internet permission in manifest file

Comment: Thanks for such brief explanation, it work,,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are required to load it through `WebViewClient`

Check and try below example given on [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) doc:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });

 webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }


}

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
```