# Android development noob: WebView usage

Tags: java, android, webview

I've been following this series of Android Development Tutorials and I've encountered some problem trying to tweak one of the projects I've created.

Basically all I want to know is how to apply the WebView correctly in my project - in the easiest and most simple way possible.

What I've done:
enabled permission to the internet on the manifest
created the webview on the main_activity.xml
imported the WebView webkit to my MainActivity Java class

And all I've done after that is simply loading the url on my onCreated method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.weblol);
    v.loadUrl("www.google.com");
}
```

However nothing seems to happen and the block of the WebView remains blank white

Care to explain to a noob what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You should use **http://www.google.com** instead of **www.google.com**.
Only you to this,webview can notice this it is a URL.

Otherwise.you can use local file in webview ,like **file:///android_asset/xxx** in assets folder.
That's all.