# How to send parameter on bank side and open the bank page

Tags: android

I want to implement the payment gateway in my android application. And i have all the things like merchant id and parameters. So how i send the parameter and open the bank page in webview in android.but only message is show that( Your payment request is being processed ). and bank page not open after that.Please provide me the code for help..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which payment gateway are you integrating? check there documentation for integration

Comment: i am implementing billdesk payment gateway.please help if u know how to implement it.

Comment: please help me , please provide me the code .. I am in trouble .

Comment: check for there documentation, i haven't integrated billdesk before

Comment: if you implement any one than provide me the code to sending the parameter on bank side and open the bank page in mobile application.please

Comment: How to load the https url in webview .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android

Comment: i am asking about HTTPS url not HTTP.

Comment: i think you ask a separate question with your problem