# errors for simple webview app in android studio

Tags: android, dictionary, android-studio, webview

i try to make a simple webview app for this interactive map: http://gta5online.com/map/interactive > there is also a fullscreen link below the map.

now i created an asset folder and included the "interactive" folder which has all the files, icons, map tiles and html document in it.

i want to load the html document from there into a activity as a webview. so its a local file. i want the app to handle it not the default browser.

here is what i did by now:

i created a new project and added those codes into the activity_home.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html");
/>
```

then i added this code to enable internet access in to manifest even if its a local html doc that i want to load (for later uses):

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

i also enabled javascript at the first code block as you can see.

should i've put some code into the home.java file too?

in a YT tutorial i saw that he used something like this in the java file:

```
      #in mainactivity.java
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url ="file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

can someone please help a noob to achieve this by explaining what i did wrong and simple steps how to complete this app?. i'm sure its simple for you guys even if its that hard for me.

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful in Android, you can never place Java code into XML code.

This code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/interactive/map.html");
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity_home.xml file must be only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: and whats with the rest like enable javascript, loading the html file etc?

Comment: What is the your  problem? Your java code (in your question) put in your MainActivity.java file in onCreate override method. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3152441/2738172

Comment: hey thanks for answer man. my problem is i'm a beginner. there was some other code inside the java folder as a standard i guess:

Comment: package comapps.gta5online.gta5interactivemapcheats;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
         }

       }

Comment: should i keep this too?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to same origin policy violation, you need to use `loaddatawithurl`

Read

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

and

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: sorry @ashish didn't get what you mean? do you say there is a android policy violation?

Comment: hey the app runs now in its basic form. check out the video: youtu.be/qUNEpZbfRDM