# using Intent.ACTION_VIEW without opening in browser

Tags: android, url, android-intent, hyperlink, arduino

I want to connect arduino and android via cc3000, it works perfectly in both side. 
well, in arduino we access http://ip/location1 and http://ip/location2.

and in android i am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://ip/location1"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and you know why i am not using

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext =  new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://ip/location1");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

it's not working, it's not even connecting

so, how to make it access the url, without opening browser? with Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Comment: call it in a web view.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i want to access url without open in browser

Answer (score 0):

You can load your url in a WebView. A Webview is an Android widget that allows you to display an webpage on your app. Check this answer for the implementation:

[how to display progress while loading a url to webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android)