# android webview load html with js

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I try to load a url in my android app, the url is [url](http://m.algo-m.com/#/appDepot?symbol=XAUUSD&connection=Real&period=1). The js in the html seems not execute. It can only show a background without charm. Below is my code :

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load a url to webview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: No need for `webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);`

Comment: thank you very much!  But it still doesn't work. it can only load a backgroud. But the chart in the html dones't show me?

Comment: thank you for your method,  It work ok for me now...Thank you very much