# Displaying white screen in WebView Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, webview

**Web view not loading**

I have followed this link

[web view example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android)

Web view is not loading , i am not able to view the page.Now Webview shows as a white screen

can you give me your suggestion to reslove this issue.

Comment: Did you add this in your manifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: have you add the internet permission

Comment: I am checking wait..

Comment: Check your Internet permission in Manifest file , And also your web URL

Comment: I missed adding permission in the manifest. Thank you all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This may work.