# Android app webview opens in browser instead of the app

Tags: android, webview

```
package com.slimolobeapp.slimolobe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //initilizing webview
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.slimolobeapp.com");
        //force links open in webview
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_shop) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.slimolobeapp.com/shop");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_category) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.slimolobeapp.com/category");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_price) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.slimolobeapp.com/price");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.slimolobeapp.com/contact");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/slimolobe");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_instagram) {
            mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.instagram.com/slimolobe");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.slimolobeapp.com")) {
//open url content in webview
                return false;
            } else {
//here open external links in external browser or app
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    //goto previous page when pressing back button

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mywebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }


        return false;

    }
}
```

Here is my main activity code, I don't know where I am doing it wrong. Every time I open the app, the web view launches a browser, the apps did not load the web page, it only loads in the browser and I don't want this.

Comment: no, i did not get an error, the webpage loads in a browser instead in the app

Comment: Add Internet permission in your manifestfile <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: i added the internet permission in the manifest file already

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview

Comment: This should solve your problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288611/how-to-load-a-url-to-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set your WebView client before you call loadUrl().

Comment: Did it work, I'm curious to know what the problem was?

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually the code is correct but my website was not config to allow www, so I have to reconfig it to allow www. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ah ok interesting glad you figured it out that was an interesting problem.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

Comment: Would you add some remarks into this answer as to how this would help? We generally discourage code-only answers, as they may not be clear for current or future readers.