# ProgressBar for WebView that takes forever to load?

Tags: android

I have a third party link to webpage that takes literally 2 minutes to load up with video.  While it is loading their is a blank page.  I have no control over the page.  Is there any way I can detect page loaded with a webview and display a loading dialog until the page appears?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do as below :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // do your stuff here
}
});
```

and also this may be helpful :

[How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android)