# How much time does a webview take to load the images attached in the webview/webpage.?

Tags: android, image, webview, load

I have been looking for android webview loading time for quite a long time now. What I want to do is to find out how much time does a webview take to load the images (and only images) attached in the webview/webpage. Please Help. I would really appreciate.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the network connection speed itself and what kind of images you would download.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to calculate the time that is taken to load just the webpage/webview images, and not the whole page on the android device. Like we have WebViewClient methods onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() to find out total page load delay.

Comment: There are not any specific images, I am talking about the images associated with the webpage itself that is being loaded.

Comment: do you want to calculate the time before the download or measure time that was required for downloading?

Comment: I want to measure the time required for images to get fully loaded/downloaded. Something like (time when image loading started) - (time when image got downloaded); this should give the image download delay

Comment: Do you download the images separately from the actual webpage and embed them into that webpage shown in the webview in the code or do they come as a single download?

Comment: No, I am just loading the url in the webview, nothing else. The images come as a single download only

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do this for just images loaded in a WebView. As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android) implement `onPageFinished()`. That's at least get you somewhere.

Comment: So there is no way to find out the load delay for images and rest of the webpage separately?

Comment: On Android, directly, I have no clue. But FYI [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) is how it's achieved with JavaScript. So if these web pages are under your control you could implement a method to monitor the image loading in them and maybe call a function which will alert your Android app, or maybe listen to from your app. I haven't done such a thing so I'm clueless on how to do that.

Comment: I have found a way to measure the image loading time, just in case somebody needs the answer. There is a method setLoadsImagesAutomatically(FLAG) that can be used to tell the webview whether to load the images or not. using mywebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false), we can disable the image loading in webview and find out the total time taken for loading(this will exclude the image loading time) and thus can be subtracted from the total webview loading time (including images).

Comment: [Excellent!](http://3beautifulbamfs.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/the_rock_clap_clap_gif.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a thread, which checks the webpage for images and retrieves their paths. Then iterate through those paths and get the filesizes.

Now you would have the filesizes and I would reckon the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class would provide some way of determining the approximate connection speed. After this you could calculate the time it takes to download the images.

However, I do not think there is out-of-box-way of doing this sort of thing and the way I described above seems an awful lot of trouble since the download time is usually relatively short.