# Show Webview when page completly done loading?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

For simplicity sake let’s say I have 1 activity that has a few textViews a progressSpinner and a webView. 
The webView visibility is set to “gone” all others are set to visible. When the page finishes loading and the 2 divs I want to remove are hidden, I want to hide all visible items and show the fully loaded webView. 
 
However when I run it I see all the visible items and the webView is not showing at this point(which is good). After a few seconds the visible items are gone and a blank webView appears(shouldn’t happen), then the page loads, then the 2 divs are hidden. 
I want to hide this from the user how can I set it to display the webView only after the page is completely done loading and the 2 divs are hidden?

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {  
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:$('#MainMenu').hide()");
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:$('#EmployeeDashboard').hide()");
    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(2500); // My attempt to allow the divs to be hidden before it's displayed to the user
    findViewById(R.id.progressSpinner).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.tvLoading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

In the xml I have:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out I was having trouble because of a redirect, this helped me: 
[How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android/5172952#5172952)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're creating your webview object then calling loadUrl(...)

After that, instead of setting the contentView to your webView, set it to your view/graphic/whatever you want to show while it's loading.

In your onPageFinished, call setContentView to your webView.

```
MyWebView myWebView = new MyWebView();
myWebView.loadUrl ("http://whatever.com/goes/here");
setContentView(R.loadingurlspinner);
```

then in your onPageFinished()

```
//stuff you have above
setContentView(myWebView);
```

Comment: I have setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

Comment: I will edit my question to hopefully explain my problem better, Thanks!