# how to get event when web view load it html (completely load)?

Tags: android

I am opening a html page in web view in android .I want get event when html page is completely loaded .I want to call some function when it load completely  ..can you please tell me on which function or event will fire when it load completely ?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/stacker.html");

        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

    }



}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via WebViewClient this way:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     // page was loaded
    }
});
```

Optionally, you can fire event in Javascript and catch it via JavascriptInterface.