# How to make a WebView visible only after it finished displaying content?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webView, where I display a HTML I fetch from the backend.
My problem is that I am trying to display a loading message, and show the content only after the page is done.
For doing that, I tried to use `onPageFinished`, which winda works, but not entirely, because it is called after the data is fetched, but BEFORE the page is displayed, so I'm still displaying a blank screen for about 1 second, before finally displaying the HTML.

From the [oficial docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29):

`public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)`

Added in API level 1
Notify the host application that a page has finished loading. This method is called only for main frame. When onPageFinished() is called, **the rendering picture may not be updated yet. To get the notification for the new Picture, use onNewPicture(WebView, Picture).**

The problem is that `onNewPicture(WebView, Picture)` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture))

So my question is, is there a way to know when the page is finished, but also fully displayed?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.messageId = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(ITEM_ID_KEY);

    this.setUpActionBar();
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox_item_detail);
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    this.fetchInboxDetailsTask(this.messageId);
}
```

Comment: One of thia guys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android says that u must set a new WebViewClient and override that method you said there.

Comment: Try to override window.onload / onloadend by evaluating Javascript in Webview page. Check out global events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers

Answer (score 0):

I have a WebView in a fragment and, just for your reference, I have set it up like this.

May be you are missing something. "**onPageFinished**" works just fine for me.

In **onViewCreated method**:

```
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.appWebView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

and then:

```
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the Advanced Webview Library for android it provides an interface to reaspond to when page start loading and when finishes! [here (AdvancedWebView)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView)