# After the 'webView.loadUrl' doned in asynk I don't see immediately the webpage

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

how can I wait to show the webView until it loads all the web data?
i have created this asynktask sketch:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url = params[0];
    webView.loadUrl(url);



    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
//progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"wait","downloading URL");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



}

}
```

it works but a the end of this code, after onPostExecute i'm still seeing the blank page of webview loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadUrl` is already doing everything asynchronously, so onPostExecute is called right away.

If you want to display a loading indicator, you need to use that :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

and of course remove you AsyncTask.

More : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android)

Comment: please can u show me a loading indicator example? for example with the progressBar that i am using. can I set the webview visibility 'Visible' only when the loading is finished?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you page has iframe and stuff like that, use another example in the link provided in my answer.