# WebView in background is still clickable when ProgressBar is shown

Tags: java, android, webview

I have my android webView app working nice. It also shows the ProgressBar while loading the url and hides it when finish the load with a beautiful effect cause I put some alpha in the ProgressBar layout to see webView in the background. I followed [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android).

**My problem is: webView is still clickable.**

`MyManifest.xml`: i have all permissions needed I think...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

`main_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    tools:context="com.siconet.axa.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I show/hide progressbar in the client and I need to avoid webView from being clicked:

`webViewClient.java`

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
{
    loadingFinished = false;

    // this works like charm
    activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activity.findViewById(R.id.webView).setAlpha(0.3f);

    // this is not working :(
    activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setClickable(true);
    activity.findViewById(R.id.webView).setClickable(false);

    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}


@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
{
    // control of the loading options....
    if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
        activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.webView).setAlpha(1f);

        // not working again :(
        activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setClickable(false);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.webView).setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

I also tried with requestFocus():

```
activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).requestFocus();
```

And adding listeners to the views:

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { // declare listener...
```

Any idea of why is this happening???

Comment: If it is not working then you can use progress dialog instead of progessbar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your `ProgressBar` element in XML:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: does not changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RelativeLayout` (the `ProgressBar` `View` parent) attributes to:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
```

This will make your `RelativeLayout` to cover your whole layout (not just 100dpx100dp) and to receive the clicks while its visible.