# How to understand when a WebView finished loading a resource?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

When I'm loading a resource in a WebView, in Android, I simply call the typical `mWebView.loadUrl(ht);`.

The problem is that I would like to check the final url, and to perform some operation, when all the redirects are finished to be followed.

I mean: if I load `example.com/page1`, and this returns a 302 code that leads to another page (let's say, `/page2`), and this leads me again via a 302 redirection to another page (`/page3`), and this finally gives me a 200 and stops there, I would like to *know* *when* this happens.

It looks like I don't have the possibility to check the response code, nor the headers, and `onPageFinished` as well as `shouldOverrideUrl` are called for *each* redirect. It's kinda like "stateless"...

How can I distinguish between a typical 302 redirect, and the actual **end of the loading process** (200)?

Comment: see this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android).

Answer (score -1):

May be setting custom WebViewClient could help you:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }
        });
```