# Progress Till Web View Loads Web Page

Tags: android, layout, webview

In my application web view takes time to load few webpages.. Is it possible to show progress till web view loads web page. I am using below code to load web page

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    String url = "http://somesites.com";
    wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For showing progress bar use this method in oncreateview in Activity :

```
private  WebView web;
private KProgressHUD pDialog;

private void setPages() {

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

    // you can use progressbar or progressdialog or any other
    // progressview here 

    pDialog = KProgressHUD.create(activity)
            .setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
            .setDimAmount(0.5f);
    pDialog.setCancellable(true);
    pDialog.show();

    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

   web.loadUrl(YOUR_URL_HERE);
}
```