# How to load URL from Gimbal notification in webview of Android app while tapping notification

Tags: push-notification, android-webview, android-ibeacon, gimbal

We are developing an android using webview with Gimbal beacons location services.We can able to get notifications once user entered location. But what we want is to load URL from that notification in the webview while tapping on notification.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)