# About WebViewClient.onPageFinished

Tags: android, android-webview

When `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` is called? When html is loaded or when html, css, js are all loaded?

When is beginning of js execution? Before `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` or after `WebViewClient.onPageFinished`?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari the question is complete. this comment doesn't require here.

Comment: Go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url

Answer (score 1):

Here are your answers.

- when you call `mWebView.loadUrl(url)` then `onPageStarted()` called, it means your page started to load.
- during the loading of page some resources like images, files, js are loading then `onLoadResource()` called, and it can called multiple times.
- when page loaded all resources and complete all its loading then `onPageFinished()` called.