# Make a WebView transparent while loading content

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way to make a `WebView` transparent (so the user can see through it to the view behind), until it's (non-transparent) content has loaded content?

`mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` works temporarily, but unfortunately the `WebView` becomes non-transparent fairly soon after the content starts loading.

The equivalent approach works on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried setting the transparency after url/data is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Simply not showing your webview until the content has loaded should have the same effect. Something along these lines: [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

@stephen's answer seems to be in right direction.

However, you can try one more approach. Make your layout structured like this

```
<FrameLayout>
   <WebView>
   <RelativeLayout> --> Rest Layout here
</FrameLayout>
```

Now as **RelativeLayout** is added after WebView, it will be visible on top of WebView, Once your webpage is fully loaded, you can hide RelativeLayout like this

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // hide RelativeLayout here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this effect by using setting the alpha value of a parent layout of the webview element to 0.01f, might work also directly on the Webview.

```
view.setAlpha(0.01f);
```

and then setting the alpha to 1 when webview finished loading in onPageFinished.

Setting the visibility to Gone/Hidden stops the Webview.