# Webview finishes loading before ALL contents are loaded

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Recently I faced a pretty annoying issue, So I am loading an iframe (youtube video) in my webview and checking if the WebView has finished loading, it works for other contents but not for iFrame, it shows the page loading finished way before the iFrame is fully loaded. I tried in both `SetWebChromeClient` and `SetWebViewClient` - In both cases, loading finishes way before the iFrame finishes loading.

I have simple `WebView`

```
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("https://.", IFRAME_HERE, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

So Setting `webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());` with the following

```
public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.Info("101029", "STARTED");
            }

            public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                Log.Info("101029", "FINISHED");
            }
```

Or setting `webView.SetWebChromeClient(new NewClient(ParentLayout, ContentLayout))` with the following

```
 public override void OnProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
            {
                base.OnProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                if (newProgress == 100)
                {
                    Log.Info("101029", "Finished");                  
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("101029", newProgress.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Same things happen, Webview shows loading is finished while the iFrame is still loading.  How do I tackle the loading of iFrames to accurately get when the iFrame has finished loading? 
any idea? Cheers

EDIT:

I also tried the following for `` (Still no luck)

```
internal class WebViewClientClass : WebViewClient
        {
            bool loadingFinished = true;
            bool redirect = false;                
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                if (!loadingFinished)
                {
                    redirect = true;
                }

                loadingFinished = false;
                Android.Net.Uri url = request.Url;
                view.LoadUrl(url.ToString());
                return true;
            }

            public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                loadingFinished = false;
                Log.Info("101029", "loading started");
            }

            public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                if (!redirect)
                {
                    loadingFinished = true;
                }

                if (loadingFinished && !redirect)
                {
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                    Log.Info("101029", "loading finised");
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172952/4984832

Comment: Hi, that is what I am doing, not working. &#39;OnPageFinished&#39;

Comment: Each Iframe will start another OnPageStarted/OnPageFinished, you are not handling that.

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried with the suggested method and updated my post - Still no luck

Comment: @SushiHangover I am still looking for the solution for this - If you have any other ideas please share :)