# How to check when content are loaded in a webview with AndroidViewClient?

Tags: android, python, webview, androidviewclient

I have an app which uses a `WebView` to display the content. The problem is that the `AndroidViewClient` dump produces the same results with only a `WebView` id whether the page is loaded or not therefore it's not possible to know when the page is loaded.
I can't type anything in the address bar of this app `WebView` to try getting the html code, no possible copy/paste too.
For the moment I use a static timeout and hope that the page is loaded within this time.
Is it possible to know when the page is loaded or even better getting the html code of this `WebView` page via `AndroidViewClient` or `adb` commands or any other external apps?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172952/9752602

Comment: this app is not mine so I can't use the java code to check the page is loaded. I use AndroidViewClient to automate this app which has the webview.