# progress bar in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-progressbar

I am trying to add a progress bar in android webview using WebViewClient. It displays the progress bar, a text (loading) and rest of the page is just a blank page.

I want to keep the current page while loading the next page and display the progress bar on the top of the current page, so that user don't have to see the blank loading page..

May someone please help me with that? How to keep the current page intake while showing the progress bar on top, until the next page is 100% loaded.

Comment: Please add some code snippets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("About CreativeGraphy");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_loading);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                setTitle("Loading....");
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //setTitle(View.getTitle());
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }
        });
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }//close activity when click back button
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

try this
it has loading

layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".About">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:progress="20"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_cyclic" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/frame_loading" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try using 2 webview if its 100% loaded visible it other one gone first will stay while other loads when it is loaded second web view starts loading

Answer (score 1):

This might Help, Source: [ProgressBar with WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)

You can trace the Progress Staus by the [getProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getProgress()) method in [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) class.

Initialize the progress status

```
private int mProgressStatus = 0;
```

then the AsyncTask for loading like this:

```
private class Task_News_ArticleView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            your_class.this);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                mProgressStatus = webview.getProgress();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```