# The progress bar above the Android webview does not stop

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

progress bar will not stop and will load indefinitely.

`Referred Page`:
[progress bar in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924547/progress-bar-in-android-webview)

**fragment code**

```
public class testFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private WebSettings mWebSettings;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public testFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testfragment, container, false);

        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pro);
//progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        mWebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mWebSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

        return v;
    }
}
```

Removing the annotation from the annotation will completely disappear the progress bar.

I also wanted to use `@Override public void onProgressChanged (WebView view, int newProgress)` on the page referenced, but it did not appear in the available methods.

Comment: You are setting 2 web clients. 
can you try by removing mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: So the issue is, you have set 2 web clients. and the last statement was overriding first one. So visible & hide was never executed. 

since in UI, you have set visibility for progress bar as visible .so it is always visible. and code is never reaching in gone one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is,
you have set `2 web clients` and the last statement was overriding the first one. So visible & hide was never executed.

Since in UI, you have set visibility for progress bar as visible .So it is always visible.

Remove `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` line.

For `onProgressChanged()`

You have to use `WebChromeClient`. Since is available in Chrome Client, not on `WebViewClient`

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I made a mistake in the basic code. It's settled well.