# How to get WebView response that returns in .js file?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my application I have credit card Link I call the URL using

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/custom_toolbar"/>

squareformwebview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
squareformwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
squareformwebview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
squareformwebview.loadUrl(API.webformCards);
```

When I run the code I am getting web page with 4 fields of credit card information and button. When I hit the button I get response in JavaScript file. Now how to handle the response? how to get token generated in response?
As far as I know Request method in POST and return format is JSON. I seen it in Network via Inspect element in browser.

Format:
{"token":1a1a147a47s4d7ffd5fdf5ds7df4,"card":"wallet_type":"NONE","card_type":"VISA","last_4":"1234","exp_month":12,"exp_year":2018,"postal_code":"1111"}}

If I miss anything in question please feel free to ask in comment.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)

Comment: use the linked question to listen to WebView page loading finished, and then just get the content from WebView

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sorry I didn't the point. How do I get the content after I enter the details and hit the submit button in OnPageFinished()?

Comment: just search for `android get content of WebView`. You should definitely try

Comment: I am searching it from yesterday, I don't understand how to get the content, what methods to follow.

Comment: What is wrong with the first link in the google by `android get content of WebView` search query?